# count distinct partition by and order by in rolling window error ORA-30487

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, window-functions

I want to `count distinct id` in rolling window and with `Partition by`

my first try

```
select login_created_at, count(distinct  account_id) over 
            ( partition by is_approved,
            is_activated_card,
            is_valid_card,
            is_first_txn
            order by login_created_at
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '29' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
            
            from data
```

error: ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here

my second try with correlated subquery referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886674/how-to-determine-the-number-of-distinct-events-in-a-sliding-window-using-oracle), but it return more than 1 row so it's failed too

```
     SELECT 
--distinct 

        day, IS_APPROVED, IS_ACTIVATED_CARD, IS_VALID_CARD, IS_FIRST_TXN,
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(DISTINCT account_id)
            FROM
                data
            WHERE
                    t2.login_created_at >= t.day - 29
                AND t2.login_created_at <= t.day
            group by             
            is_approved,
            is_activated_card,
            is_valid_card,
            is_first_txn
               ) AS login_rolling_30
    FROM
        t
    WHERE
        t.day = trunc(sysdate - 1);
```

error : ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

sample data

```
ACCOUNT_ID| LOGIN_CREATED_AT   | LOGIN_ID
42890      26-JAN-22  00:00:00  F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4A9F4
166568     26-JAN-22  00:00:00  85F80D5E-DEA2-4A4E-ABB9-46D97069E87B
260237     26-JAN-22  00:00:00  746DD48C-00A6-4FE5-B93B-46DE9E4B8D9F
145998     26-JAN-22  00:00:00  8BBDF71A-DD4E-4983-B43F-46DF6F27361F
148912     26-JAN-22  00:00:00  BE6F37CE-C4B0-4749-976D-46E1EA07E95A
189686     26-JAN-22  00:00:00  2A084C2A-F45D-497F-9A81-46E2ADACF89F
```

Comment: post some sample data to try your query?

Comment: @Sund'er I have added sample data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count(distinct) over (partition by... doesn't work in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347200/countdistinct-over-partition-by-doesnt-work-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: its not about that partition window is not working. (according to  ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row error)
its about that your subquery which is grouped by 4 columns is returning more than 1 row.
You could join that table, instead of subquerying it, if its supposed to return more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it wright - you are asking about the possibility to use dynamic windowing within the analytic function. It is like roling the rows underneath a frame that changes its size depending on certain conditions. I could offer you something that you coul try on your data making the changes to fit your goal.
Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select  '42890' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('27-07-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", 'F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4A9F4' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD", 'YES' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select  '42890' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('28-07-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", 'F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4GGGG' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select  '42890' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('24-08-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", 'F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4FFFF' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select '166568' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('24-08-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", '85F80D5E-DEA2-4A4E-ABB9-46D97069E87B' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED",  'NO' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD", 'YES' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select '260237' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('29-07-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", '746DD48C-00A6-4FE5-B93B-46DE9E4B8D9F' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select '145998' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('24-08-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", '8BBDF71A-DD4E-4983-B43F-46DF6F27361F' "LOGIN_ID",  'NO' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select '148912' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('24-07-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", 'BE6F37CE-C4B0-4749-976D-46E1EA07E95A' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select '145998' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('24-08-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", '8BBDF71A-DD4E-4983-B43F-46DF6F27AAAA' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select '148912' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('24-08-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", 'BE6F37CE-C4B0-4749-976D-46E1EA07ZZZZ' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select '166568' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('20-07-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", '85F80D5E-DEA2-4A4E-ABB9-46D97069XXXX' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual Union All
            Select '189686' "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('24-08-22', 'dd-mm-yy')  "LOGIN_CREATED_AT", '2A084C2A-F45D-497F-9A81-46E2ADACF89F' "LOGIN_ID", 'YES' "IS_APPROVED", 'YES' "IS_ACTIVATED_CARD", 'YES' "IS_VALID_CARD",  'NO' "IS_FIRST_TXN" From Dual 
        )     
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY ACCOUNT_ID, LOGIN_CREATED_AT

/*  R e s u l t     

ACCOUNT_ID LOGIN_CREATED_AT LOGIN_ID                             IS_APPROVED IS_ACTIVATED_CARD IS_VALID_CARD IS_FIRST_TXN
---------- ---------------- ------------------------------------ ----------- ----------------- ------------- ------------
145998     24-AUG-22        8BBDF71A-DD4E-4983-B43F-46DF6F27361F NO          YES               YES           NO           
145998     24-AUG-22        8BBDF71A-DD4E-4983-B43F-46DF6F27AAAA YES         YES               YES           NO           
148912     24-JUL-22        BE6F37CE-C4B0-4749-976D-46E1EA07E95A YES         YES               YES           NO           
148912     24-AUG-22        BE6F37CE-C4B0-4749-976D-46E1EA07ZZZZ YES         YES               YES           NO           
166568     20-JUL-22        85F80D5E-DEA2-4A4E-ABB9-46D97069XXXX YES         YES               YES           NO           
166568     24-AUG-22        85F80D5E-DEA2-4A4E-ABB9-46D97069E87B YES         NO                YES           YES          
189686     24-AUG-22        2A084C2A-F45D-497F-9A81-46E2ADACF89F YES         YES               YES           NO           
260237     29-JUL-22        746DD48C-00A6-4FE5-B93B-46DE9E4B8D9F YES         YES               YES           NO           
42890      27-JUL-22        F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4A9F4 YES         YES               YES           YES          
42890      28-JUL-22        F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4GGGG YES         YES               YES           NO           
42890      24-AUG-22        F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4FFFF YES         YES               YES           NO           

 11 rows selected
*/
```

Here some IDs repeats, and some not. Again, if you want just one row per ID (Distinct ACCOUNT_ID) looking through a changing frame then you could consider something like this extended dataset that I am presenting just to try to explain the logic of the answer. The answer itself is much simpler and shown at the end of this post.

```sql
SELECT 
    ID_COUNT, ACCOUNT_ID, LOGIN_CREATED_AT, LOGIN_ID, IS_APPROVED, IS_ACTIVATED_CARD, IS_VALID_CARD, IS_FIRST_TXN,
    WINDOWING_CLAUSE_APPLIED, FROM_DATE, ROW_DATE_DIFF
FROM
    (
        Select 
            t.*,
            To_Char(( Select Count(*)   
                  From tbl 
                  Where LOGIN_CREATED_AT = t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT And t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT Between TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') - 29 And TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') 
                )) || ' PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW' "WINDOWING_CLAUSE_APPLIED",
            --
            --
            TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') - 29 "FROM_DATE",
            --
            --
            TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') -
            Min(t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT) OVER( Partition By  t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT Order By t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT
            ROWS BETWEEN 
                ( Select Count(*)   
                  From tbl 
                  Where LOGIN_CREATED_AT Between TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') - 29 And TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') 
                ) PRECEDING AND 
                  CURRENT ROW) "ROW_DATE_DIFF",
            --
            --
            Count(t.ACCOUNT_ID) OVER( Partition By  t.ACCOUNT_ID Order By t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT
            ROWS BETWEEN 
                ( Select Count(*) "ROWS_BEFORE"  
                  From tbl 
                  Where LOGIN_CREATED_AT = t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT And t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT Between TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') - 29 And TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') 
                ) PRECEDING AND 
                  CURRENT ROW) "ID_COUNT"
        From 
            tbl t
    ) x
ORDER BY x.ACCOUNT_ID, x.ID_COUNT
```

There are some new columns just to explain the logic behind the changing window. You will need just the ID_COUNT column to get the result. You can see below the changing windowing clause applied along with absolute framing date 29 days before SysDate and row number of days before SysDate.

```sql
/*  R e s u l t     
  ID_COUNT ACCOUNT_ID LOGIN_CREATED_AT LOGIN_ID                             IS_APPROVED IS_ACTIVATED_CARD IS_VALID_CARD IS_FIRST_TXN WINDOWING_CLAUSE_APPLIED                                           FROM_DATE ROW_DATE_DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------------- ------------------------------------ ----------- ----------------- ------------- ------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------ --------- -------------
         1 145998     24-AUG-22        8BBDF71A-DD4E-4983-B43F-46DF6F27361F NO          YES               YES           NO           6 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22             2 
         2 145998     24-AUG-22        8BBDF71A-DD4E-4983-B43F-46DF6F27AAAA YES         YES               YES           NO           6 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22             2 
         1 148912     24-JUL-22        BE6F37CE-C4B0-4749-976D-46E1EA07E95A YES         YES               YES           NO           0 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22            33 
         2 148912     24-AUG-22        BE6F37CE-C4B0-4749-976D-46E1EA07ZZZZ YES         YES               YES           NO           6 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22             2 
         1 166568     20-JUL-22        85F80D5E-DEA2-4A4E-ABB9-46D97069XXXX YES         YES               YES           NO           0 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22            37 
         2 166568     24-AUG-22        85F80D5E-DEA2-4A4E-ABB9-46D97069E87B YES         NO                YES           YES          6 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22             2 
         1 189686     24-AUG-22        2A084C2A-F45D-497F-9A81-46E2ADACF89F YES         YES               YES           NO           6 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22             2 
         1 260237     29-JUL-22        746DD48C-00A6-4FE5-B93B-46DE9E4B8D9F YES         YES               YES           NO           1 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22            28 
         1 42890      27-JUL-22        F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4A9F4 YES         YES               YES           YES          0 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22            30 
         2 42890      28-JUL-22        F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4GGGG YES         YES               YES           NO           1 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22            29 
         3 42890      24-AUG-22        F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4FFFF YES         YES               YES           NO           6 PRECEDING And CURRENT ROW                                        28-JUL-22             2 

 11 rows selected
*/
```

The code selecting ID_COUNT is the code that contains the changing window applied to every particular row ...

```sql
Count(t.ACCOUNT_ID) OVER( Partition By  t.ACCOUNT_ID Order By t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT
            ROWS BETWEEN 
                ( Select Count(*) "ROWS_BEFORE"  
                  From tbl 
                  Where LOGIN_CREATED_AT = t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT And t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT Between TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') - 29 And TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') 
                ) PRECEDING AND 
                  CURRENT ROW) "ID_COUNT"
```

... inner select within the windowing clause changes its value of preceding rows depending on the actual row's date and number of days to look in the past for. Description is in mentioned WINDOWING_CLAUSE_APPLIED column. This result set gives us the info about days diff till SysDate so this could be used for filtering the data if you want to. I didn't use it in the answer.
Here is the code that may be usefull for you. With the sample data from above here is the code ...
**Answer**

```sql
SELECT 
    ACCOUNT_ID, LOGIN_CREATED_AT, LOGIN_ID, IS_APPROVED, IS_ACTIVATED_CARD, IS_VALID_CARD, IS_FIRST_TXN
FROM
    (
        Select 
            t.*,
            Count(t.ACCOUNT_ID) OVER( Partition By  t.ACCOUNT_ID Order By t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT
            ROWS BETWEEN 
                ( Select Count(*) "ROWS_BEFORE"  
                  From tbl 
                  Where LOGIN_CREATED_AT = t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT And t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT Between TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') - 29 And TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd')
                ) PRECEDING AND 
                  CURRENT ROW) "ID_COUNT"
        From 
            tbl t
          Where
               t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT Between TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') - 29 And TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd')
    ) x
WHERE
    x.ID_COUNT = 1
ORDER BY x.ACCOUNT_ID, x.ID_COUNT
```

... and it's resulting dataset:

```sql
/*  R e s u l t 
ACCOUNT_ID LOGIN_CREATED_AT LOGIN_ID                             IS_APPROVED IS_ACTIVATED_CARD IS_VALID_CARD IS_FIRST_TXN
---------- ---------------- ------------------------------------ ----------- ----------------- ------------- ------------
145998     24-AUG-22        8BBDF71A-DD4E-4983-B43F-46DF6F27AAAA YES         YES               YES           NO           
148912     24-AUG-22        BE6F37CE-C4B0-4749-976D-46E1EA07ZZZZ YES         YES               YES           NO           
166568     24-AUG-22        85F80D5E-DEA2-4A4E-ABB9-46D97069E87B YES         NO                YES           YES          
189686     24-AUG-22        2A084C2A-F45D-497F-9A81-46E2ADACF89F YES         YES               YES           NO           
260237     29-JUL-22        746DD48C-00A6-4FE5-B93B-46DE9E4B8D9F YES         YES               YES           NO           
42890      28-JUL-22        F7EB1B3E-070E-45D2-9B75-46D459E4GGGG YES         YES               YES           NO           

 6 rows selected
*/
```

I am not sure that the where clause filtering absolute date boundary makes any sense here. I left it just in case that you would need something like that too.
Maybe it would be better to exclude this WHERE clause...

```sql
          From 
            tbl t
          Where
               t.LOGIN_CREATED_AT Between TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd') - 29 And TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd')
    ) x
```